# Invariant interval and gravity

Tags: general-relativity, gravity

Gravity is inversely proportional to the *distance* between objects.

Do we use Euclidean distance or the invariant interval for that distance?

Using the invariant interval makes everything a bit more complex: An object that is one lightyear away, is also one year "younger" when we observe it. Does that temporal distance contribute, so that when we calculate trajectories and physical phenomena on a distance - they are different from what's observed locally?

Does this affect observed things such as the trajectory of two equally distant (from us) objects and rotational velocity of distant objects?

An example:

When we look towards the center of the milky way, we're looking about 27 000 years back in time; i.e. the temporal distance is 27000 years, and spatial distance is 27 kly

When we look at the center of the andromeda galaxy, it's about 25 Mly away. When we look at another object in the andromeda galaxy, which is also 25 Mly away - the temporal distance between those objects, *relative to us* is 0.

So; *is the relative temporal distance between objects and the observer incorporated in Einsteins field equations?*

Comment: Are you talking about gravity in the context of Newtonian or Einsteinian (i.e. general relativistic) physics?

Comment: @Danu I assume that if you use invariant interval, it de facto becomes relativistic physics?

Comment: Are you aware of the distinction between special and *general* relativity? Special relativity says nothing about gravitation specifically, while *general* relativity completely redefines it.

Comment: Pedant alert: Gravity has an inversely proportional potential; force scales by $r^{-2}$

Comment: @Danu I'm working on my understanding of special relativity, but that leads me to look for observed effects - of which gravity is probably the most easily observed.

Comment: I saw this comment thread grow while I wrote my (short) answer. Advice to the OP: Do *not* think about gravity when trying to understand SR. Gravity is the region of GR, try thinking about electromagnetic phenomena (mainly light being emitted/travelling/whatever) when thinking about SR.

Comment: @frodeborli - Special relativity addresses situations where gravitation is negligible. Newtonian gravitation addresses situations where velocities are small compared to the speed of light, masses are small (e.g., the Sun is small), and distances are large compared to Schwarzschild radii. Trying to use special relativity and Newtonian gravity to understand what happens when gravitation is not negligible and velocities are high is not a good idea because now you're moving to a regime where neither theory is applicable.

Comment: @Frodeborli Please don't bring in the EFE's when you say you're not bringing in gravity.

Comment: @HDE226868 Well, to me that's just semantics - and focusing on semantics does not help me. The answer to the question was simple; time is just as important as any other spatial coordinate and is incorporated identically.

Comment: @frodeborli: rather than get into all of these digressions about general relativity, which are relevant to your exact question, perhaps it would be easier to see how they measure the "r" in the $\frac{1}{r^{2}}$ dependence in Gauss's law within the context of special relativity:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retarded_potential

Comment: The basic trick is that the distance considered is the distance from where the field is measured to where the charge distribution WAS when a lightray from that point in the hcarge distribution hit where the field is being measured.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gravity (the potential that is, not the *force*) is only inversely proportional to *actual, spatial* distance in the Newtonian approximation of GR, also known as the *weak field limit*, i.e. for bodies (like the earth) that are very far from becoming a black hole. One obtains it e.g. in the [Schwarzschild solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric) of GR for $\frac{r_S}{r}\ll 1$.

But, in general, gravity is not proportional to anything - the presence of matter determines the geometry of spacetime through the [Einstein field equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations), and "gravity" is the observation that that geometry differs - in whatever form - from the gravity-free flat space that is Minkowski space.

About the temporal distance being included or not included - the Einstein field equations are, as a tensor equation, invariant under arbitrary coordinate transformations, just as every good SR equation is invariant under Lorentz transformations. Both invariances mean that the term *temporal distance* (which is **not** invariant) cannot really play a role in these, because, from another frame, that temporal distance will be different (or non-existent, or have a different sign). You can, invariantly, talk about spacetime distances being *time-like*, *light-like* or *space-like* depending on their sign. But, there is nothing to *include* here - no matter whether SR or GR, we have given up on assigning any special treatment to time: It is *just another coordinate* on the spacetime manifold (well, in SR, it's the one with the odd sign in the metric, but that's really it), and our equations and techniques apply to everything on that manifold equally.

Comment: I think OP wants you to talk about Newtonian gravity, 'enhanced' by a restriction on the speed of light ;)

Comment: I've tried to reformulate my question; my question is not about gravity - it's about observed effects.

Comment: @frodeborli: You've lost me. *Yes*, what we "observe" is not always what we "calculate" (see e.g. [Terrell rotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrell_rotation) for the actual *observation* of the Lorentz contraction), but I don't get what you are asking about the trajectories - what do you mean by *different*, and why do you think they should be?

Comment: @ACuriousMind I believe distant objects that have a temporal distance, as observed by *us* to be 0 should display different behaviour than objects that have a temporal distance of for example 27000 years. I added an example.

Comment: @frodeborli: You still haven't told us *what difference* in behaviour you would expect and why. And it is really not obvious (to me).

Comment: First of all; time being treated equal, *just another coordinate* really answers my question. You then really have to take the invariant interval into account everywhere. As a result, I have a hunch that this means that more distant galaxies generally should *appear* heavier than nearby galaxies. For all I know, this is also predicted by Einstein.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I believe the big bang shot everything out in an arbitrary four dimensional direction. It seems somewhat natural that we'll see a uniform red shift. Due to gravity; mass will "come together" in four dimensions Something moving either slower, or faster than us in the time dimension will appear red-shifted - regardless of direction. Things local to us in the universe must necessarily be travelling along a more similar world-line to us, and be less red shifted. (This is just my speculation, and I might change my mind after thinking some more)

Comment: @ACuriousMind +1: Well put.  I'd add that it's not only in SR that there *is* something "different" about time since Lorentzian manifolds, even curved ones, have non-Euclidean signature.

Comment: @ACuriousMind +1 indeed, short, concise and understandable.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this should clarify:

Let's say you're looking at a ball of negative charge 1 lightyear away, but that it disappeared 6 months ago (i.e., you still see it). You still feel the negative charge because the **electric field lines from the ball travel precisely at the speed of light.**

*Edit*: Since gravitational field lines also travel at the speed of light, the same effect holds true for the effect of one massive object on another in space.

Comment: I don't feel that this is an answer to my question, and it'll be hard to measure anyway. I'd place a (small) bet on the *propagation* of gravity occuring at the speed of light, but once the field has been set up, a change in direction and distance may be instantaneous. I guess this could be tested by observing two objects travelling in parallel in space.

Comment: *I don't feel that this is an answer to my question,[...]* It really is an answer to your question. If you believed that the gravitational force depended on the invariant interval, then for an event 1 ly away and 1 year in the past, the interval would be zero. Would the gravitational force then be infinite? Clearly not.

Comment: *The question is then do "gravitational field lines" travel at the speed of light, or are they instantaneous? I have read differing views on the subject but most have suggested the former - but I am open to correction.* This is not controversial. Gravitational effects propagate at c.

Comment: @BenCrowell Thanks, for some reason I couldn't find anywhere that stated that clearly.