# Gravity in spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime

Can the effect of gravity in spacetime be thought of as if nearby particles have a tendency to "align" their four velocity direction? I.e. "to point in the same direction".

Comment: No. In fact, I think the tendency is opposite, since gravity *attracts*. However, as has already been pointed out to you, it's not very convenient or useful to think about gravity in the context of SRT because it is inconsistent with Newtonian gravity, while also not being capable of dealing with it in a different way (e.g. through *general* relativity).

Comment: Well, if they are flying from each other, the attractive force makes them "more aligned". Once they are aligned, gravity continues to "misalign them", to approach each other, but then they reach the minimum distance (avoiding collision, assume it) and the description is different again. Gravity sometimes aligns them, sometimes does the opposite.

Comment: At any rate, it is bizarre to discuss these trivial - Newtonian - phenomena with words such as "Minkowski spacetime". Relativity is clearly not needed to see whether gravity makes two velocity vectors approach each other or the opposite. So relativity has nothing to do with the simple Newtonian exercise. Relativity has nothing to do with making distant objects' properties directly change, either. In fact, a key point of relativistic theory of gravity -general relativity - is really the opposite one. Objects only influence each other through the spacetime medium in between, not instantaneously.

Comment: Related question by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/133675/2451

Comment: @LubošMotl Why are you saying "gravity is a Newtonian phenomena"? Are you saying that gravity is not a phenomena in relativity? I'm pretty sure you're misunderstanding my question. The moon orbits the earth. If the earth is then accelerated, the moon will probably follow - although it's trajectory will become less stable relative to earth. So my question is; the four velocity of the moon seems to align with nearby massive objects - and the trajectory instability is similar to a momentum effect in four dimensions.

Comment: I am saying that gravity is a Newtonian phenomenon because Isaac Newton is the #1 person in the human history who may be credited for that phenomenon because he published the universal law of gravitation, back in 1687, and it was the key part and application of his more general theory of classical mechanics. This Newtonian picture of gravity is surely sufficient to answer questions such as whether world lines tend to align or misalign themselves which is why I pointed out that any discussion of relativity in this rudimentary context is pure red herring.

Comment: @LubošMotl This is not a discussion. I'm simply asking for a confirmation that my line of thought is correct according to special relativity - *not* in terms of Newtonian gravity.

Comment: Your line of thought is not correct according to special relativity and it has nothing to do with special relativity. In fact, special relativity (in the strict sense, not including general relativity) is a theory that explicitly prohibits any gravity. Your line of thought is incorrect according to any viable theory – especially classical mechanics – too. You are really asking about the simple properties of the fate of the direction of velocities under the gravitational influence and any viable theory that isn't immediately ruled out confirms that what you say about the convergence is wrong.

Comment: @LubošMotl Still; special relativity explains trajectories in terms of curvature of spacetime. So my question is still valid; does the four velocity of objects tend to align or not inversely proportional to their distance?

Comment: @LubošMotl I feel you should post your answer as an answer, and not as a comment - and I'll eventually accept it unless somebody else disagree.

Comment: No, special relativity prohibits any curvature of spacetime. It is really hard to talk about these matters if you confuse special and general relativity - which is a pretty elementary mistake - yet you seem extremely self-confident about all the wrong things you are writing down. ... I don't believe that you will accept (or even upvote) an answer that unequivocally implies that your question - something you self-evidently consider a big discovery - is really just a basic confusion and mistake. That's why I am avoiding the controversy that results from posting answers to "very wrong" questions.

Comment: @LubošMotl If I were very self confident in these matters, I wouldn't be spending my time *asking* these questions. I'm merely seeking to understand this. It becomes a problem to ask, if the person answering becomes hostile. The value of a question is always relative.

Comment: But you have been given the answers several times in about 10+ comments here (starting with Danu's "No") so why do you keep on repeating the stuff that you want others to "confirm" your claims? Has there been any ambiguity about the conclusion that your proposition is incorrect? How many kilobytes of texts do you need to understand "No"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16890/discussion-between-frodeborli-and-lubos-motl).

Comment: Incidentally, the correct claim about "straightening of trajectories" is one that one may derive from the relativistic theory of gravity, general relativity, but the dynamics isn't trying to make the trajectories "parallel to other objects' trajectories". Instead, general relativity implies that the trajectories of freely falling bodies are straightest possible (geodesics) according to the local (generally curved) geometry of the spacetime.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Gravity, in GR terms, is the tendency of particles to follow, in the absence of other forces, the [geodesics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic) on the spacetime manifold as determined by the metric on it, which is in turn determined by the distribution of matter through the [Einstein field equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations).

The four-velocity of a particle is the tangent vector to its worldline (which is, with only gravity, a geodesic). Saying that gravity *aligns the four-velocities* with each other is, without further refinement, non-sensical, because *you cannot compare* vectors<sup>1</sup> at different point of the manifold, as they live in different [tangent spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space). Note that, in the simplest case of the [Schwarzschild metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric) there are all the circular orbits we know and love from Newtonian gravity around the point mass. Two orthogonal orbits of these will certainly not be *aligned* in any meaningful sense, ever, neither with each other, nor with the worldline of the central mass.

---

<sup>1</sup>Yet, the metric determines a notion of comparing the vector at different points - the  [Levi-Civita connection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_connection), which allows us to ["parallel transport"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_transport) vectors along paths, "preserving" their orientation. With this language, geodesics - the paths particles follow under the influence of gravity - are precisely those paths along which *parallel transporting* their tangent vector does not change it (for a suitable notion of "does not change" defined by the connection, see the articles linked).